# Can a coupon be programmatically added to an order using the add to cart subscriber?

Tags: commerce

I'm attempting to add a coupon to an order when an item is added to the cart.  I've added an event subscriber for `commerce_cart.entity.add`. Within the subscriber, I use `$to_apply->getPromotion()->apply($event->getCart());`.

This does end up in `Promotion::apply()` and does call `$offer->apply()`, but the coupon doesn't seem to actually get applied.  I've tried to see if, once we arrive at /checkout/{order_id}, the promotions/coupons are reset. AFAICT, they are not.

I have confirmed that I can manually apply the coupon once on /checkout/{order_id}.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer via Slack.  You only need to update the `OrderInteface` and set the `coupons` property, then resave the order.  `PromotionOrderProcessor` handles applying the coupon to the order.

Something like this should work within your event subscriber:

```
  /** @var \Drupal\commerce_promotion\Entity\Coupon $to_apply */
  $to_apply = $coupon
  /** @var OrderInterface $cart */
  $cart = $event->getCart();
  $cart->set('coupons', $to_apply);
  $cart->save();
```